# utf8 character from cp437 is garbled when rendered via JS, not when php rendered

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, meta

I have stored text in my database as utf-8. The text may contain some ascii art from the code point U+2500 to U+25FF range in the utf-8 table, perhaps even other code point ranges. I'm not sure since this is user edited. The text is delivered to the client using JSON over REST, and somehow the text is distorted along the way.

The utf-8 character range I'm referring to here, is of a three byte nature. For instance, a set of `0xe2 0x96 0x93` would in utf-8 equal `&#x2593;` or as plain text ▓. Instead of displaying this single character, the client displays each individual byte as it's own character, which would end up displaying `â–‘`

Not sure how to attack this. I've tried to figure out a way to convert the text server side using php, but the utf-8 table is just to large for me, and checking for every potential three byte combination is just overwelming. This should be easy. I've seen this done before, but then the entire page was rendered server side. This is an angularJs page.

Can anybody give me pointers as to solve this problem? Thank you.

**Edit: stripped down code (php rendered)**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <?
        $link = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_db);
        $result = $link->query('select descr from my_table where id = 1');
    ?>
    <div class="well"><?=$result['descr']; ?></div>
    ...
</body>
```

*Would display:*

> ░░                                                                      ░░
>
> ```
>   ▒░                                                                      ░▒
>   ▓░                                                                      ░▓
>   ▓░                                                                      ░▓
>   █░                                                                      ░█
>   █                                                                        █
>   █▓                                                                      ▓█
>   ▓▓▌                                                                    ▐▓▓
>   ▀██▄                                                                  ▄██▀
>  ▄ ▄████▓▓▓█▄█▀▀    ▀▀           ▄   ▄▄▄▌▄▓████████████████████████▓▀▓████▄ ▄
> ```

**The same database table queried using Laravel and sent over http async (also largely stripped down code):**

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {
    public function getDescriptionAttribute($value) {
        return $value;
    }
}

class MyModelController extends Controller {
    public function getModel ($modelId) {
        return Response::json(MyModel::findOrFail($modelId));
    }
}
```

---

```
angular.module(_SERVICES_).factory('MyModelService', ['Restangular', function (Restangular) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        get: function (id) {
            return Restangular.one('model', id).get();
        }
    }
}

angular.module(_CONTROLLERS_).controller('MyModelCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'MyModelService',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, MyModelService) {
        MyModelService.get($routeParams.modelId).then(function (response) {
            $scope.model = response;
        }
    }
}

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ...
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyModelCtrl">
    ....
    <div class="well" ng-bind-html="model.descr"></div>
    ...
</body>
```

*Would display*

> ```
> â–‘                                                                  
> â–‘
> â–‘â–‘                                                                      â–‘â–‘
> â–’â–‘                                                                      â–‘â–’
> â–’â–‘                                                                      â–‘â–’
> â–“â–‘                                                                      â–‘â–“
> â–“â–‘                                                                      â–‘â–“
> â–ˆâ–‘                                                                      â–‘â–ˆ
> â–ˆ                                                                        â–ˆ
> â–ˆâ–“                                                                      â–“â–ˆ
> â–“â–“â–Œ                                                                    â–â–“â–“
> â–€â–ˆâ–ˆâ–„                                                                  â–„â–ˆâ–ˆâ–€
> â–„ â–„â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–“â–“â–“â–ˆâ–„â–ˆâ–€â–€    â–€â–€           â–„   â–„â–„â–„â–Œâ–„â–“â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–“â–€â–“â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–„ â–„
> ```

**Edit2: Request/Response headers**

*PHP rendered page*

```
Request Headers
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nb;q=0.6,nn;q=0.4,no;q=0.2
Cache-Control: no-cache Connection:keep-alive
Host: example.com Pragma:no-cache
Referer: http://example.com/mymodel.php?id=1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36 

Response Headers
Cache-control: private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 
Date: Tue, 29 Jul 2014 20:18:10 GMT 
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 
Pragma: no-cache Server:Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.28
```

*Async request/response*

```
Request Headers
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nb;q=0.6,nn;q=0.4,no;q=0.2
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: example.com
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://www.example.com/modelview/1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36

Response Headers
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 3669
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 30 Jul 2014 12:29:11 GMT
Expires: Wed, 30 Jul 2014 12:29:11 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=96
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.28
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
```

Comment: You should investigate the "somehow the text is distorted along the way". Does PHP correctly recognize that this is a single three-byte character? Or does PHP think that you have three separate characters? If the latter, then you can probably fix the issue by making PHP aware that these are multibyte characters.

Comment: There is no logical (or otherwise) reason for it to be distorted. The text is queried from the database and outputted to a json directly. What arrives at the client is exactly the same if examined hexadecimally. It just wont output a three byte character. Every byte is displayed as it's own character - hence the "distorted" part.

Comment: Does the database realize that these are multibyte characters? (Also, I'm not sure what "outputted to a json directly" means. Despite your "directly", that still implies that conversions are happening . . .)

Comment: I'm not sure... How can I tell what either mysql or php "realizes" about my string? Regarding "outputted to a json"; yes converted from a resultset in array form to a resultset in json form. JSON = JavaScript Object Notation. I assumed that everybody knew what this lightweight replacement to xml was these days.

Comment: You can tell what MySQL or PHP realizes by (for example) asking them how long it thinks these strings are. If it says "three characters" for something that's supposed to be one three-byte character, then you have your answer. (And yes, I know what JSON is, thank you very much. But you're talking in abstractions. There is a low-level problem with your data representation, but instead of showing low-level code, you're being very handwavy with your insistences that there's no reason for anything to be going wrong.)

Comment: I'm sorry if I offended you. That was completelly unintentional. The reason I'm handwavy is that I can produce a php rendered page with the exact same data outputted correctly, but once transferred async over http, it looses it's multibyte reference. It would seem that the problem then would lie in how angular receives the data. Wont you agree? I can produce a sample above if you like...

Comment: No worries. As for the problem being in how angular receives the data -- I'm not sure. You can use your browser's development tools to see exactly what's going back and forth. In addition to the possibility of problems inside angular, it also seems possible that something is going wrong due to the Accept headers being sent to your server, or that your browser is more permissive with mislabeled UTF-8 in HTML than in JSON data.

Comment: Ok, then how can I preserve the art as entered by the user? What you are saying is that the text is scrambled on input and not output? Then how come I can render it propperly when page is rendered server side?

Comment: It seems as if your code uses charset ISO-8859-1 somewhere along the line. I was able to reproduce the exact (undesired) result as your example when I used it as the charset. Check the code at the top of the page that outputs the garbled characters to verify if `<meta charset="utf-8">` is within the `<head>` tags.

Comment: My page contains that meta tag, yes. I've included the request/response headers for both the php rendered page and the async request above.